# Can't save texture on tileset resource in Godot

Tags: godot

New to Godot so sorry if this is a dumb question, but I haven't seen tutorials that explain this. Godot is running as admin in Windows.

I have a scene and a tilemap node and a tileset resource. When I add a texture to the tileset, I can configure it no problem and saving gives no problematic messages. However, if I navigate away from the tileset or double click on the same tileset, the texture disappears. I cannot begin to edit my tilemap because no tiles are recognized. On top of that if I add readd my texture, the snap options are set correctly already so this means that my configuration is being saved somewhere, just not in my tileset right?

Why is my texture being deleted from the tileset? Why is my work not saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add textures to the `TileSet` you need to define tiles in them. Adding a texture does not automatically make it a tile (in fact, you might define multiple tiles in the same texture).

You have three options to define tiles:

- "New Single Tile": Lets you define tiles one by one
- "New Autotile": Lets you define a group of tiles for, well, autotiling.
- "New Atlas": Lets you define tiles in batch.

You can read more about this in [Creating a TileSet](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/using_tilemaps.html#creating-a-tileset).

*Once you created the tiles, you can define their collider, navigation polygons and so on.*

Any textures that doesn't have tiles defined will not be saved with the `TileSet`. So, if you are adding the textures, but not defining tiles in them, they will disappear from the editor.

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue. Since my tiles were decorative with no collisions, I thought that just setting the snapping options was enough.